# How to "zip" Tensorflow Dataset and train in Keras correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a `train_x.csv` and a `train_y.csv`, and I'd like to train a model using Dataset API and Keras interface. This what I'm trying to do:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

N_FEATURES = 10
N_SAMPLES = 100
N_OUTPUTS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 8
EPOCHS = 5

# prepare fake data
train_x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N_SAMPLES, N_FEATURES))
train_x.to_csv('train_x.csv', index=False)
train_y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N_SAMPLES, N_OUTPUTS))
train_y.to_csv('train_y.csv', index=False)

train_x = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset('train_x.csv', [tf.float32] * N_FEATURES, header=True)
train_y = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset('train_y.csv', [tf.float32] * N_OUTPUTS, header=True)
dataset = ...  # What to do here?

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_OUTPUTS, input_shape=(N_FEATURES,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('linear'),
])
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=N_SAMPLES/BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

What's the right way to implement this `dataset`?

I tried [`Dataset.zip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip) API like `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_x, train_y))` but it seems not working(code [here](https://pastebin.com/7nX8bxus) and error [here](https://pastebin.com/ikfZZ88E)). I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46140332/2666624) answer, it's working but I'd like a non-functional model declaration way.

Comment: `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_x, train_y))` should work. What error did you get?

Comment: @Sharky code and error has been updated. The error is [this one](https://pastebin.com/ikfZZ88E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the input shape of your dense layer. It should match shape of your input tensor, which is 1. 
`tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_OUTPUTS, input_shape=(features_shape,))`

Also you might encounter problems defining `model.fit()` `steps_per_epoch parameter`, it should be of type `int`.
`model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=int(N_SAMPLES/BATCH_SIZE), epochs=EPOCHS)`

Edit 1:
In case you need multiple labels, you can do

```
def parse_f(data, labels):
    return data, tf.stack(labels, axis=0)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_x, train_y))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_func)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
```

Comment: But by design the input shape should be N_FEATURES not 1, as my train_x has shape (N_SAMPLES, N_FEATURES).

Comment: That's right, input shape is (batch, input), input is itself 1d array. Have you tried the code from my answer?

Comment: You mean `input_shape=(1, )`? Not working I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you getting the following error `ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected...` ? If so, there is a shape mismatch in your random data, it should be `train_y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N_SAMPLES))`
see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899248/keras-model-valueerror-error-when-checking-model-target

Comment: But my network should have two outputs, that's why the N_OUTPUTS exists. And the `train_y` cannot be a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N_SAMPLES))` will create a dataframe of shape  `[N_SAMPLES rows x 1 columns]`, so one label per training example. Is your situation different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189001/discussion-between-icyblade-and-sharky).